# AWS to non AWS SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am setting up the architecture for an AWS project and I am pondering which service of AWS to use.

I have some data stored in RDS(MySQL or Oracle) in AWS. <strike>The use case demands to ssh the data from RDS to a non-aws instance.</strike>  As the data is stored in RDS, I need to send some formatted/massaged data to a client(non-aws instance) via ssh by either enabling the ssh channel from the RDS (EC2) instance - which I don't prefer or using something else from the AWS umbrella-like lambda functions. The data that I need to ssh will be in csv format in sizes of KB's or in small MB's so I don't a big ETL tool for doing this.

The data in RDS will be populated via AWS Lambda.

Spinning up a separate EC2 instance just for this (to ssh to the client) will really be a kill.

What are the options I have?

Comment: There is no concept of using SSH to access a database. SSH is used to login to a command-line in Linux. Could you please Edit your question and expand upon what you mean by "ssh the data from RDS to a non-aws instance"? For example, what is on that target instance? In what format would you like the data? Can you describe your end-to-end process?

Answer (score 0):

You can always take advantage of aws serverless umbrella.

So if you want to massage the data and then ssh to non aws instance you can use aws glue and do your processing and also orchestrate it using glue workflows.